# Why does exponential smoothing in statsmodels return identical values for a time series forecast?

Tags: python, time-series, signal-processing, statsmodels, smoothing

I am using the following code to get simple exponential smoothing in `statsmodels`.

```
years = [1979,1980,1981,1982,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1988]
mylist = [3.508046180009842, 64.08556070923805, 15.407086104154587, 0, 3.8572598099708557, 11.009202659130096, 5.324577212333679, 4.33474725484848, 4.024865210056305, 5.065838277339935]

import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.api import ExponentialSmoothing, SimpleExpSmoothing
myinput = pd.Series(mylist, years)
fit_model = SimpleExpSmoothing(myinput).fit()
smoothed = fit_model.fittedvalues
print(smoothed.tolist())
```

The result I got was quite surprising. i.e. I get the same value for every year.

```
[11.661719028226004, 11.661719028226004, 11.661719028226004, 11.661719028226004, 11.661719028226004, 11.661719028226004, 11.661719028226004, 11.661719028226004, 11.661719028226004, 11.661719028226004]
```

I am wondering why I get the same value for every year. Please let me know how to fix this?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is raised if the index is not of type `DatetimeIndex` or `RangeIndex`.

In your case the list is simply converted to a "normal" `Int64Index`.

I tried several things, e.g. converting converting the index to a 
`RangeIndex`

```
myinput = pd.Series(mylist, range(1979, 1989))
```

or a `DatetimeIndex`

```
years_index = [datetime(_, 1, 1) for _ in years] 
myinput = pd.Series(mylist, years_index)
```

but then there is another exception.

I think the solution to your problem is to supply the keyword argument `smoothing_level` to the fit like

```
fit_model = SimpleExpSmoothing(myinput).fit(smoothing_level=0.2)
```

Then the returned numbers are not identical. I did not check the results, but most of the code for plotting can be found in the [statsmodel tutorial](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/exponential_smoothing.html).

The default value seems to be `smoothing_level=None`, but I am not sure why the fit function is not working out of the box.

The docs only state

> The smoothing_level value of the simple exponential smoothing, if the value is set then this value will be used as the value.

[This](https://otexts.com/fpp2/ses.html) is the description of the simple exponential smoothing method as mentioned in the docs if you are interested in how the smoothing level is defined.

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation:

"Simple exponential smoothing has a “flat” forecast function.

That is, all forecasts take the same value, equal to the last level component. Remember that these forecasts will only be suitable if the time series has no trend or seasonal component."

https://otexts.com/fpp2/ses.html

Comment: so whats the point of this forecast function if it doesnt actually forecast anything ?

Comment: @orenrevenge All it's doing is predicting that the future values are the weighted average of the observed past values.  If you have a series of [8, 12, 9, 11], it'll predict that all future values are about 10 or so.  It's literally just doing the weighted average.  It's slightly more complicated than the Naive model, which is just predicting that every future value will be the same as the last observed value.